# Не работает фуркция render() при Pjax-запросе

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

Доброго времени суток, у меня есть форма(ActiveForm), которую я пытаюсь передать через Pjax. Проблема в том, что в контроллере не срабатывает функция render().

Форма:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([

                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'form form-horizontal',
                    'data-pjax' => 'true',
                    'name' => 'changePassForm'],
                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}",
                    'options' => [
                        'tag' => false,
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
//Поля
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Контроллер:

```
public function actionRequestchenge() {

       if(Yii::$app->request->isPjax){
            return $this->render('success');
        }
}
```

Ничего не возвращает(при том что return работает). Pjax тоже работает, не перезагружает страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день.
Замените обычный **render()** на **[renderAjax()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#renderAjax()-detail)**

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Comment: Еще вопрос, когда я вставляю в код pjax, он добавляет свой контейнер <div data-pjax-container=""> в те места, где я его открываю/закрываю, соответственно ломает мою верстку, не подскажете как можно это более-гуманно пофиксить?

Comment: Попробуйте изменить при помощи **options()**
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$options-detail

Comment: Pjax по-умолчанию доступен только для чтения, так что решил проблему через css, спасибо.

Comment: А какой html Вы хотите в результате получить и какой получаете сейчас?

Comment: Я так понял вы комментируете к моей другой теме. Сейчас передаю форму ActiveForm и хочу получить другую ActiveForm, то есть содержимое 2 степа регистрации. Сейчас покидаю скрины.

Comment: нет, я именно в эту тему пишу))) Вы написали, что не смогли изменить контейнер pjax. Вот мне стало интересно, что Вы хотите получить в конечном счёте.

Comment: Хотел изменить его, он по умолчанию приписывал мне блок с max-width=320px, что ломало мне верстку. Я изменил main.css, убрал ненужный max-width  и все нормально

Comment: Вот это и можно изменить при помощи **options()**